# In a Ruby Class that Inherits from String, How do I Get "#{my_string}" with explicit .to_s

Tags: ruby

In short, I expect all three #{}s in the final line of this test program to result in the same string and they don't.  It works if my class inherits from Object.

```
> ./test.rb 
A string foobar, and MyString: , MyString.to_s: foobar

> cat test.rb 

    #!/usr/bin/env ruby

    class MyString < String
      def initialize s
        @s= s.to_s
        @simple = s.index(?+)
      end
      def to_s() @s end
    end

x='foobar'

puts "A string #{x}, and MyString: #{
        MyString.new(x)}, MyString.to_s: #{MyString.new(x).to_s}"
```

Comment: The [actual use case](https://github.com/GerryG/wagn/commit/adad0a4f0a777a2c0c3d27db7ff747a539ec0414#commitcomment-1126867) is a bit more complicated.  The new method needed some tweaking too.  Thanks to the people who answered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As [Niklas B. demonstrates](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9848187/214790), string interpolation doesn't call `to_s` on `String` objects. The default value for the argument to [`String#initialize` is `""`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/String.html#method-c-new), so instances of your subclass are all in effect empty strings.

One way to get this to work is to call `super` in the `initialize` method if your subclass, and pass the string value:

```
class MyString < String
  def initialize s
    super s.to_s    # this line added
    @s= s.to_s
    @simple = s.index(?+)
  end
  def to_s() @s end
end

puts "#{MyString.new("foo")}"  # => produces "foo"
```

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense.  I was almost to figuring this out.  I thought that somehow 'self' wasn't really getting a value, and this is why.

Answer (score 4):

It seems like string interpolation handles objects of type `String` differently:

```
irb(main):011:0> class MyString < String
irb(main):012:1>   def initialize(str)
irb(main):013:2>     @str = str
irb(main):014:2>   end
irb(main):015:1>   def to_s
irb(main):016:2>     puts "to_s called!"
irb(main):017:2>     @str
irb(main):018:2>   end
irb(main):019:1> end
=> nil
irb(main):020:0> "#{MyString.new('foo')}"
=> ""
```

As you can see, `to_s` is not even called. The reason for that is the invariant `str.to_s == str` where `str.is_a? String`. You broke that invariant, thus confusing the library code.

**Conclusion**: Don't override `to_s` if you're subclassing `String` (it doesn't make a lot of sense anyway).

Comment: I did run into cases where I needed the String object, not the MyString object.  I did that as "#{self}" in one place. but now I'm thinking that this is just self.to_s which is syntactically simpler.